# If docker container is a process how it can be restarted?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker container is defined in the offitial doc as a process ?

How much is this precise since process by definition are always running and can't be stopped/restarted ?

Comment: How did reach the conclusion that the  "process[es] by definition are always running and can't be stopped/restarted" ?

Comment: For a process: kill = stop, exec = restart.

Comment: @BMitch we exec a programme, and we kill a process. my questions was asked because I have never known a processs that is not running I am wondering what does it mean to have a stopped container (a serialization of the process state may be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers are a process with some configuration and namespaces attached to them for isolation. That configuration includes which image to use, and any settings you passed on the `docker run` command or from inside your compose yml file. You can view this configuration with a `docker container inspect`.

Part of the namespaces attached to the container is a filesystem namespace that includes a read/write layer for any changes you have made inside the container that weren't written to a volume. You can view a list of these changes with a `docker diff` on your container.

When you stop the container, the running process is killed, however the configuration and the container filesystem remain. If you restart the container, the process is restarted with the same configuration. When you delete a container, this configuration and the read/write filesystem layer are removed.

Comment: Thank you, That confirme what I understund. So they are not process they don't have PID, they creates associated processes when running, but when stopped they are just containers NOT PROCESS to be PRECISE

Comment: To say that a container is a process is to drive home that a container is not a VM. It's not running a separate kernel, it's just a wrapper around running a Linux process under the same host kernel.

Comment: They are NOT PROCESS they create process ONLY when running. it is VERY IMPORTANT to be PRCEISE naming things when doing technical stuff to don't confuse people